# Is there a way to set a different Safari download folder per website?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

Is there any way in Safari (6 on Mountain Lion) to have it remember a different download folder per website?

So if I visit my bank and download a statement I can pick my /finance/ folder to download to and have it remember that location for future visits.
Meanwhile I can go to basecamp and have anything I download there go straight to /work/

In Firefox there's a secret flag you can set that allows this behaviour, is there any way to do the same thing in Safari or through an extension?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to do it in Safari. The only things you could do is use a Shell script to move stuff around (based on file types or so). Or you can use the Automator to define rules for your download folder. A good alternative, which specifically focusses on file management is [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php).